# Storing Array of Control Pointers in GAS

Tags: google-apps-script

The code below works just fine, it fills a FlexTable with placeholders which represent days on a calendar (columns), against rooms in a hotel (rows). Some of the code which was out of context was removed, so what is shown here will not execute. But what the client handlers do is hide every room (entire column) for any cell when selected, then a 2nd client handler unhides the cell selected. This prevents the user registering 2 rooms for the same day, and makes the experience more interactive. So far, so good.

Of course when it comes to resetting the calendar, I have some other code which loops every cell selected, and unhides all the cells in the related columns using the control Ids to reference the grid locations. But what should be possible, is to reference the same array of actual controls as the one used to construct the clienthandler.

So simply, is it possible to store an array of class references? Both CacheService and PropertiesService only store strings - have I missed something?

```
var vCaledarSelectors = {};

for(var r=0; r<iRows; r++){   
  for(var c=1; c<iCols+2; c++){

    var sControl = 'calendarSlot_' + r + '_' + c;            
    var oSlotLabel = app.createLabel()
    .setId(sControl);      

    if(r==0){
      vCaledarSelectors[c] = [];
    };

    vCaledarSelectors[c].push(oSlotLabel); // STORE THE CONTROL POINTER IN ARRAY                
    oCalendar.setWidget(r, c, oSlotLabel);      
  };
};  

for(var vSlotCol in vCaledarSelectors){

  // HIDE ALL CONTROLS IN THE COLUMN
  var chandlerColVisOff = app.createClientHandler().forTargets(vCaledarSelectors[vSlotCol]).setVisible(false);      
  for(var vSlot in vCaledarSelectors[vSlotCol]){
    // UNHIDE THE EVENT SOURCE CONTROL
    var chandlerSlotVisOn = app.createClientHandler().forEventSource().setVisible(true);

    vCaledarSelectors[vSlotCol][vSlot].addClickHandler(chandlerColVisOff).addClickHandler(chandlerSlotVisOn);
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing an array as a string (and retrieving it as an array) can be achieved using different approaches, one of them is to use `JSON.Stringify(array)` and `JSON.parse(string)` methods as documented [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

But in many cases (simple arrays) you can simply use `join()` and `split()` that will use commas as default delimiter. Or choose the delimiter yourself if, for some reason, there can be commas in the array elements; I use uncommon characters like `∏` or `|` that are visually easy to read but you can use what you want in the form `join('delimiter')` and `split('delimiter')`.

Example :

```
[a,b,c].join('|') is a string : "a|b|c"

"a|b|c".split('|') is an array : [a,b,c]
```

Comment: thanks Serge, and I haven't tried what you suggest, but since the array contains classes (or references to them), I assumed applying JSON would render them unusable?

Comment: you're right... I guess I didn't read closely enough the request... I shall remove this answer. Why not saving their IDs instead ?

Comment: no worries - I could use their Ids, but since we are able to use an array of the classes themselves in clienthandlers etc, I thought we might be able to store them and then reference entire groups of controls similarly